# adding usernotification category without permission dialog popping up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to add interactive notification categories without the notifications permissions dialog popping up?  The problem is if they hit "Don't Allow" on the original notifications permissions dialog, but then later change the notification setting manually, your categories never get added and there doesn't seem to be anyway to add them back.  Is there anyway to separate the two?

I've tried:

```
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction* snoozeAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
[snoozeAction setIdentifier:@"snooze_action_id"];
[snoozeAction setTitle:@"Snooze"];
[snoozeAction setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
[snoozeAction setDestructive:NO];
[snoozeAction setAuthenticationRequired:NO];



UIMutableUserNotificationCategory* SnoozeCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
[SnoozeCategory setIdentifier:kNotifCategory];
[SnoozeCategory setActions:@[snoozeAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
[SnoozeCategory setActions:@[snoozeAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

NSSet* categories = [NSSet setWithArray:@[SnoozeCategory]];
//NOT asking for permission to send any type of notifications here, just making sure our categories get saved
UIUserNotificationSettings* settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeNone categories:categories];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

As you can see im setting the notification settings to UIUserNOtificationTypeNone, but the permissions dialog still pops up.

Comment: That setting is not to let you bypass it. you need to check if you grant the permission using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]

Comment: yeah but what happens if they click "do not allow" how do you ever add the categories back?

Comment: To me, i would just add that after granting the permission. If there is no permission, alert would be appear.And check permission again when the app becomes foreground.

Comment: Im not communicating the problem effectively i think.  If they click NO on the notifications permissions dialog. They will never see it again unless they uninstall the app for 24 hours. If they manually turn on notifications for your app in the settings menu, the categories still do not get added.

Comment: So in your scenario, after you register the settings querying them back shows exactly what was set before the new registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on [registerUserNotificationSettings:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerUserNotificationSettings:)

> The first time your app launches and calls this method, the system asks the user whether your app should be allowed to deliver notifications and stores the response. Thereafter, the system uses the stored response to determine the actual types of notifications you may use.
>
> ...
>
> Calling this method with a new user settings object **replaces the previous settings request**.

So I think what you can do is wrap your code in a method that gets called on each app launch (maybe in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or even `applicationDidBecomeActive:`). The user will only be prompted once and if they reject and enable later your new method should add the correct settings.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work, If I just call [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes..] Everytime I launch and they've manually turned on notifications it looks like my categories get added in.